# VBA Arrays - Subscript Out of Range, Having Trouble Looping Array and Loading into New Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

This is a follow up question to my previous VBA question. Someone provided me with a potential solution for a lag in performance, and mentioned instead of looping through the actual cells in each column, transform the columns into Arrays and then load the results into a new Array.

I keep getting "subscript out of range" issues, among other various errors. I've manipulated these Arrays so many times with ReDim and others to try to load the results, but I keep hitting the same issue. You will see some of the code I tried where things are commented out.

How can I properly load these results based on the information I have? I thought at first it was because I was declaring a dynamic, empty Array, so that's why I used the UBound of an array of the same size in a ReDim.

```
Sub Missing_CAT():

Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
'Dim j As Long
'Dim h As Long
'Dim h As Variant
Dim d As Date
Dim e As Date
Dim f As Date
Dim a As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim secondRowCount As Long
Dim oDateArr() As Variant
Dim fromDateArr() As Variant
Dim toDateArr() As Variant
Dim perilArr() As Variant
Dim resultArr() As Variant
Dim cell As Variant
Dim counter As Variant
Dim count As Long
Dim boundary As Long
Dim ub As Integer


rowCount = Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

oDateArr = Sheets("raw_data_YOA").Range("Q2:Q" & rowCount).Value

ub = UBound(oDateArr)

ReDim resultArr(ub)

count = 0
'For i = 2 To rowCount
For Each i In oDateArr

    'd = Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(i, 17).Value
    d = i
  
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name = "2020" Or ws.Name = "2019" Then
            
            secondRowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row
            fromDateArr = ws.Range("D5:D" & secondRowCount).Value
            toDateArr = ws.Range("E5:E" & secondRowCount).Value
            perilArr = ws.Range("F5:F" & secondRowCount).Value
           '  For j = 5 to secondRowCount
             'For Each j In fromDateArr
             'boundary = UBound(fromDateArr)
             For j = 1 To UBound(fromDateArr)
               ' MsgBox (fromDateArr(j))
                    e = fromDateArr(j, 1)
                    f = toDateArr(j, 1)
                    p = perilArr(j, 1)
                    'e = ws.Cells(j, 4).Value
                    ' f = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
                If d >= e And d <= f Then
                  ' ReDim Preserve resultArr(1 To UBound(resultArr) + 1)
                   ' resultArr(UBound(resultArr), 1) = p
                        resultArr(count) = p
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf j = UBound(fromDateArr) Then
                       ' Worksheets("raw_data_YOA").Cells(i, 63).Value = "FALSE"
                       ' ReDim Preserve resultArr(1 To UBound(resultArr) + 1)
                      '  MsgBox (UBound(resultArr))
                        resultArr(count) = "FALSE"
                    End If
             Next j
        Else
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        
count = count + 1
NextIteration:
        Next
Next i

counter = 0
For Each cell In Sheets("raw_data_YOA").Range("Q2:Q" & rowCount)
     cell.Value = resultArr(counter)
     counter = counter + 1
Next

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Specifically, the lines throwing the errors are `resultArr(count) = ...`

Comment: `For Each i In oDateArr` is a red flag. Arrays should be iterated over with a loop like `For i = LBound(oDateArr) to UBound(oDateArr)`. `For j = 1 To UBound(fromDateArr)` is also problematic due to the hard-coded 1.

Comment: @BigBen I understand - I appreciate that being point out, but that doesn't solve the issue. Additionally, the hard coded 1 is because it starts at the first index of the array everytime it restarts the loop, since it's comparing a date (i) across the same range of dates (j) every time. Just realized I should probably start that at 0, but anyways, there's more to solving this I believe.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `LBound`. What line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen Will do. The line throwing the errors are the `resultArr(count) = ...`

Comment: If you `Debug.Print LBound(resultArr), UBound(resultArrr), count` - what is the result in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen Tried changing `For Each i In oDateArr` to the `i = LBound(...) to UBound(..)` as you suggested, didn't work so I switched it back. Did the `Debug.Print` after changing back and it get "0 8601 8601" and it continues counting backwards by 2 up until 8205?

Comment: Change `d = i` to `d = oDateArr(i)` too. Don't use a `For Each` loop for an array.

Comment: @BigBen I did, and I was getting the same errors as I do with the resultArr()

Comment: Add the `Debug.Print` *right* before you attempt `resultArr(count) = ...` and step through the code with F8 or add a breakpoint on the `resultArr(count)` line... then report back the result in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @BigBen Yes I did.. and I said I received "0 8601 8601" counting backwards by 2 to "0 8601 8205"

Comment: Is this supposed to do the same as the code in your previous question? And is the code in the previous question working as expected (except that it is too slow)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes! I just changed it back to what it was originally and implemented the solution that was originally down voted by someone. That fixed it, and it's working properly. I'm going to leave up this post though in case someone has a fix for my question that could benefit someone in the future.

Comment: I'll look into it.